# How to Sum previos rows summatory to find a balance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm working on a service that needs to calculate how much a customer owes, according to a total invoice value and the partial payments that the customer has made.

So, in a tableA I have a row with the invoice total value:

[dbo].[TableA]

```
ID    CustomerId    InvoiceVal    
1     12            1000           
2     11            2000   
3     10            5000   
4     14            15000   
5     12            100   
6     16            8000   
7     18            3200
```

In a TableB I have the record of each customer's partial payments they have made to each invoice:

[dbo].[TableB]

```
ID    InvoiceId    Payment
1     1            150   
2     3            50
3     1            120
4     1            100
5     5            90
6     4            7500
```

So, as you can see, the customer 12 has an invoice for $1000 and has made 3 payment that sum $370

I need to be able to se the partial total owed in each row, this is the expected result:

```
No.    InoviceId    CustomerId    Payment    Owed
1      1            12            150        850
2      1            12            120        730
3      1            12            100        630
```

So far, this is my code:

```
DECLARE @invid int = '1'

DECLARE @invoicetotal numeric(18,2)

SET @invoicetotal =
    (
        SELECT
            [dbo].[TableA].[InvoiceVal]
        FROM [dbo].[TableA]
        WHERE
            ([dbo].[TableA].[ID] = @invid)
    )

SELECT
    *,
    SUM(@invoicetotal - [dbo].[TableB].[Payment]) OVER(ORDER BY [dbo].[TableB].[ID] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS [Owed]
FROM [dbo].[TableB]
WHERE
    ([dbo].[TableB].[InvoiceId] = @invid)
```

But this is what I get:

```
ID    InvoiceId    Payment    Owed
1     1            150.00     NULL
3     1            120.00     850.00
4     1            100.00     1730.00
```

I need to sum the previous payment on each row.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would help

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TableB.ID ASC) NO,
  CustomerId,
  Payment,
  InvoiceVal - SUM(Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY TableA.ID ORDER BY TableB.Id ASC) Owed
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.Id = TableB.InvoiceId
WHERE 
  CustomerId = 12
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2787361d58129e56744131d592eda917)

Answer (score 1):

Your query will depend on what you are trying to make as your final output.

If you want just *ONE* `CustomerID`, go with:

```
SELECT a.ID AS InvoiceID, a.CustomerID, a.InvoiceVal AS StartInvoice
  , b.ID AS bid, b.Payment
  , a.InvoiceVal - ISNULL(SUM(b.Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.id),0) AS owed
FROM TableA a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.InvoiceID
WHERE a.CustomerID = 12
```

And if that `CustomerID` doesn't have any payments, you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` so that you don't eliminate an amount owed.

```
SELECT a.ID AS aid, a.CustomerID,  a.InvoiceVal AS StartInvoice
  , b.ID AS bid, b.Payment
  , a.InvoiceVal - ISNULL(SUM(b.Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.id),0) AS owed
FROM TableA a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.InvoiceID
WHERE a.CustomerID = 11
```

I also added an `ISNULL()` around `Payment` to keep from `null`ing out your `owed` amount. It could also be added to the `InvoiceVal` to account for a CustomerID who hasn't been invoiced yet, if that was needed (or possible from other tables).

IF you want to get *ALL* `CustomerID`s, you'll have to account for that in your partition.

```
SELECT s1.CustomerID, aid AS InvoiceID, s1.bid, s1.Payment
    , (s1.StartInvoice - s1.runningPayment) AS Owed
FROM (
    SELECT a.ID AS aid, a.CustomerID, a.InvoiceVal AS StartInvoice
      , b.ID AS bid, b.Payment
      , ISNULL(SUM(b.Payment) OVER (PARTITION BY a.CustomerID, a.ID ORDER BY b.id),0) AS runningPayment
    FROM TableA a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.InvoiceID
) s1
ORDER BY s1.CustomerID, s1.aid, s1.bid
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=913cd9887696fccc01b5d404e4d206fa) demonstrates overpayment or paying total balance for 0 owed.

Comment: I just noticed that my single-CustomerID answer is almost identical to Simonare's. If you need the `No.` column to track the payment number, add the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. And the primary difference being a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` to keep from excluding `Owed` amounts if someone hasn't made a payment.

Comment: Also note that your Payment is currently being ordered by just `ID`, so if you add a row to account for a Payment Date, then that would probably be a much better way to sort for a running total.